# Convert Type to Generic Class Definition

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to convert a `System.Type` to Generic Type definition, so I can use it to call Generic methods. Basically the reverse of `typeof`.

Example (i used "classof" where I would need the real solution so that you see where I got a problem, as classof is not a real .NET method):

```
public class BaseAppContext {

    private Type settingsType;

    public Type SettingsType
    {
        get { return this.settingsType; }
        set { this.SettingsType = value; }
    }    

    public void MyFunction() {
      MyStaticClass.GetData<classof(this.SettingsType)>();
    }
}
```

Just some more information why I am using this strange way to handle the problem. BaseAppContext is a class that is refered to by a lot of other classes. If I would would make it Generic that would mean a lot of other parts of the code would change, which I don't want. I am writing a framework, so I would like for the framework to input the type once, and the developers can just use the provided functions without having to deal with the type everytime they try to call a method.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  What would you be able to do with a `List<classof(X)>`? What about constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.
Generics form compile-time types; you cannot create a compile-time type from a type known only at runtime.

Instead, you need to use reflection, or use a different design (eg, a non-generic method).

Comment: Laks, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771628/getting-the-dbcontext-dbsets-using-reflection-and-having-a-cast-to-the-proper-ge) seems related, how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 9):

This won't be possible, since `SettingsType` is set at runtime and code between `<>` is compiled.

You can create an instance of your type like this:

```
var type = Type.GetType(SettingsType);
var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

and cast `inst` to an interface or base class.

Since you're using a static class, rich's answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you'll need to use reflection:

```
public void MyFunction() {
  var method = typeof(MyStaticClass).GetMethod("GetData").MakeGenericMethod(SettingsType);
  method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

However, I would not recommend doing this and would instead advise redesigning your solution. Using reflection means that you miss out on all the lovely compile time safety that the language provides. This generally leads to more brittle, less maintainable code.